# Authenticating in angular / ionic with $http and php / Yii

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova, yii

I am trying to authenticate to a Yii API (Yii Version 1.1.15) using an ionic / angular app, and can't get headers within the PHP page.

The angular code is:

```
 $http({
        headers: {'X_ASCCPE_USERNAME': username,'X_ASCCPE_PASSWORD': password},
        url: 'http://example.com/index.php/',            
        params: {r: 'api/list',model: 'users',callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'}
    })
```

and the PHP code is:

```
    $username = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_'.self::APPLICATION_ID.'_USERNAME'];
    $password = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_'.self::APPLICATION_ID.'_PASSWORD'];
```

but the username and password are not set in
`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_ASCCPE_USERNAME']` and
`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_ASCCPE_PASSWORD']`.

The only place I see these is  `HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS==>accept, x_asccpe_password, x_asccpe_username`

How do I pass these from angular ($http) to PHP / Yii ?

Comment: This looks to be an issue with Angular: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1004

Answer (score 0):

You are prepending `HTTP_` to the header. But it is not needed.

Change your php code to:

```
$username = $_SERVER['X_'.self::APPLICATION_ID.'_USERNAME'];
$password = $_SERVER['X_'.self::APPLICATION_ID.'_PASSWORD'];
```

Comment: @Krill That's not correct and causes a server error. You don't include HTTP_  when you send, but you need it to parse on receiving end.